# Yii2 Model validation is not working as expected

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to validate a simple form in Yii2 framework. 
validation method on model is -

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('name', 'required'),
            // ... other rules
        );
    }
```

When i try to make request it says -

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Name cannot be blank." } }
```

But the thing is i am sending name field in request ( POST ). But after providing name field , it gives an error.

If i do `var_dump` for `request` It shows me that name field is in there the request.

Here is the `var_dump` of request data and the validation error. -

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "distro" } array(1) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Name cannot be blank." } }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code of your action in controller so we can see how are you setting/validating the data?

Comment: try `$model->name = Yii::$app->request->post("username");` before validate

Comment: can you attatch code of controller>action for better solution

Comment: You have to load the requested data to the model before validates by using `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` method. This method will help you to map the requested data to the model.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understanding your question, your problem is in your name of input.
In `Yii2 ActiveRecord` all data is in array of model name. for example:

Your models name is `Users`, when you using ActiveRecord your data must send like this to rules work on it:

```
{
    'Users' => {
        'username' => 'john_doe',
        'fullname' => 'John Doe',
    }
}
```

so change your html form input name to: `model_name[field_name]`

like this :

```
<input type="text" name="Users[username]">
```

Comment: I am using ajax to send request , content type is json. - 

`{
    "users" : {
        "username"=> "john_doe",
        "fullname" => "John Doe"
    }
}`

But its still giving the same error.

Comment: @TrueCode please update your question and send your code and model name.

Comment: This is not completely true. The form inputs uses capitalized model names not snake case so it shoud be `Users[username]` (`ModelName[field]`). Also it is not neccessary to keep this structure. The `\yii\base\Model::load($data, $formName = null)` method's second param decides where to look for data. When `$formName` is `null` model name is used and it looks for data in `$data[$formName]`. But when the empty string is used instead the attributes are loaded directly from `$data`.